# Editing a string to include variables between brackets c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I have a string `filename` which contains the name of a file eg. example.plt. I would like to edit this string by inserting a integer variable between two brackets at the end of the string like so:
example.plt --> example(1).plt

What I've tried is removing the file extension (.plt), adding the brackets with the integer variable and adding back the extension but I can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
filename = filename.erase(filename.length() - 4); //example.plt - .plt = example
filename = filename + "(" + i + ")" + ".plt"; //example + ( + i + ) + .plt = example(i).plt
```

The idea is that when I later create a file with the name example.plt I don't overwrite an existing example.plt but instead create a new file example(1).plt. If someone could help me with the correct syntax for this or suggest a more elegant way to do this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You really should use the facilities provided to you by either `<filesystem>` or your OS when it comes to splitting up file names.  You shouldn't need to mess around with figuring out what part of the name is the extension, etc.  Once you have the name split into its components, then it is trivial just to put the name back together with the numeric suffix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie as you say it isn't the ideal way to go about it but it is the only way I could think of with my limited experience. If you could elaborate on how I might use <filesystem> to achieve this I would be glad to learn how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i` is an `int`, then you need to convert it to a `string` first, using the [`to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) method.

```
filename = filename + "(" + std::to_string( i ) + ")" + ".plt";
```

As stated by PaulMcKenzie in the comments though, you should be using [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) to get the file name, extension, etc..

Example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string filename = "apples/oranges/example.plt";
    std::filesystem::path path = filename;
    std::string name = path.stem().string();
    name += '(' + std::to_string( 1 ) + ')' + path.extension().string();
    path.replace_filename( name  );

    std::cout << path; // output: apples/oranges/example(1).plt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert `i` to a string.

You can use e.g. [std::to_string()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) for that.

```
#include <string>
filename =...
filename+="("+std::to_string(i)+").plt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you described

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "example.plt";
    filename = filename.erase(filename.length() - 4);
    filename = filename + "(" + std::to_string(2) + ").plt"; // You can replace the 2 with i
    std::cout << filename << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With the output:

```
example(2).plt
```

If this doesn't work it might be helpful to post what error you are getting when you try to compile or what your code is outputting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++ 17 or greater, using [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), the generation of the `(x)` tail for the name can be generic.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::string generate_name(const std::string& name, int value)
{
    std::string ext = fs::path(name).extension().generic_string();
    std::string stem = fs::path(name).stem().generic_string();
    return stem + "(" + std::to_string(value) + ")" + ext;
}

int main()
{
    std::string name = "filename.plt";
    std::cout << generate_name(name, 1) << "\n";
    std::cout << generate_name(name, 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << generate_name("another_name.txt123", 1) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
filename(1).plt
filename(2).plt
another_name(1).txt123
```

Note this now works, regardless of the extension length.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can see how this would be a more useful and modular solution. Would this also work using <boost/filesystem>?

Comment: Yes, it should also work with `boost`.  Maybe the functions to get the extension and name may be different, but I'm sure it will look similar to the solution.

Comment: `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` and `namespace fs = boost::filesystem;` should be the only changes you need (with the addition of linking with the boost filesystem library).

Comment: Glad to hear it, once again thank you for the help.